# Swap Case of Strings in R

Tags: r

Would like to setup a function that changes case of all strings from UPPER to lower and lower to UPPER.   So "THIS is a TEST" would result as "this IS A test".  I have tried to use toupper and tolower individually with no success.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Use `chartr` like this:

```
chartr("A-Za-z", "a-zA-Z", "THIS is a TEST")
## [1] "this IS A test"
```

**2)** Not as simple but still base R and one line:

```
gsub("([A-Z])|([a-z])", "\\L\\1\\U\\2", "THIS is a TEST", perl = TRUE)
## [1] "this IS A test"
```

Comment: Good to learn about the chartr() function. I was going to post this as an answer, but yours is better... paste(sapply(strsplit(mystring, ""), function(x) ifelse(grepl("[A-Z]", x), tolower(x), toupper(x))), collapse="")

Answer (score 2):

A different possibility involves the library `snakecase`:

```
to_any_case("THIS is a TEST", case = "swap")

[1] "this IS A test"
```